# PL/SQL. Cannot extract values from xmltable

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xmltable

I am trying to send a clob and then destructure it like:

This is how I am sending the message:

```
declare
  messageClob clob;
  log_id number;
begin
  log_id := 12; --for testing
  messageClob := to_clob(
  '
      <myReq xmlns="http://xxx/xx/x" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xxx/xx/x file:/C:/Users/User1/Documents/test.xsd">
         <signature>HelloWorld</signature>
         <status>End</status>
         <mydate>2005-03-29T13:24:36.000</mydate>
      </myReq >
  ');
  my_pkg.getMyReq(p_messageClob => messageClob,
                  p_logId       => log_id);
end;
```

And this is the code to desctructure it:

```
  procedure getMyReq(p_messageClob clob, p_logId number) is
    logHistoryId number;
  begin

    if p_messageClob is not null then
      dbms_output. put_line(p_messageClob);

      for message In (select * from xmltable(
                        xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxx/xx/x'),
                        'myReq' passing xmltype(p_messageClob)
                        columns
                          signature varchar2(50) path 'signature',
                          status varchar2(10) path 'status',
                          mydate date path 'mydate')) 
      loop
        dbms_output.put_line(message.signature || ', ' || message.status|| ', ' || message.mydate );
       
      end loop;
    end if;
  exception
    ...some code
  end getMyReq;
```

What am I missing here? This is the same scenario as always and still there is noting printed. I am sure that message is not null because `dbms_output. put_line(p_messageClob);` prints the clob.

Comment: Is your exception handler squashing an error? Unless your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to match the ISO format the implicit date conversion will throw an error, for instance.

Comment: ooohh.. I forgot to print this error... This was actually  wrong date format. It is solved now. Thank you for a hint!

Comment: `2005-03-29T13:24:36.000` is really timestamp format, because it contains ms part, even though they are 0

Comment: Actually, NLS doesn't matter in this context; XMLTable is expecting ISO-8601 formats. But still, you've said it's a date, not a timestamp, and squashed the error it causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
mydate date path 'mydate'
```

(and your procedure squashing the error). It is effectively doing `to_date('2005-03-29T13:24:36.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` which throws the same error.

You can either retrieve it as a string:

```
mydate varchar2(23) path 'mydate'
```

and convert it later, or retrieve it as a timestamp, which even handles the ISO-8601 'T' separator unlike Oracle's timestamp literal:

```
mydate timestamp path 'mydate'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9b2cf9da402ac6c5521bba44421e5174)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use to_timestamp with `on conversion error` clause:

```sql
      for message In (select 
                        signature,
                        status,
                        to_timestamp(
                            mydate default null on conversion error,
                            'YYYY-MM-DD"T"hh24:mi:ssxff'
                        ) mydate
                      from xmltable(
                        xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xxx/xx/x'),
                        'myReq' passing xmltype(p_messageClob)
                        columns
                          signature varchar2(50) path 'signature',
                          status varchar2(10) path 'status',
                          mydate varchar2(27) path 'mydate'))
```